# How to capture fingerprint using HTML and VeriFinger?

Tags: java, html, fingerprint

I'm developing a system whose requires to capture user fingerprint. I have done this task using a desktop app in Java.

I need to do it via web using a form or dialog, but I have no idea how to do it. I want to avoid applets. Is there a way to place a button in HTML and capture a fingerprint?

I'm using [verifinger sdk](http://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html)

**UPDATE**
I sent a message to Verifinger team and they sent me this:

- Trial SDK package includes all the functionality, including VeriFinger Extended.

Before starting to implement these questions should be raised and answered:

- Will your solution be able to interact with user's computer?

If you want your browser application to use client side fingerprint scanners and you want to use Neurotechnology components for it - you should write an applet (Java) or ActiveX component and then embed it to C# asp.net application (sorry we do not have sample for that). There are other ways of implementation but the applet is a general approach.

- Will your solution be able to extract biometric templates on client side?

If you want your application to extract and/or do matching on client pc - you will have to use either an applet or ActiveX (in order to run code that references our libraries on clients pc). If you do not want to do that - you can capture an image (either with our components, or maybe just allowing client to select a file), upload it to the back-end (running C# ASP.NET, Java EE or even PHP), do processing there, return the results.

In general the Java Applet sample is a good place to start: you can use it for image capture and/or template extraction and write your own middleware (like enrollment to database or matching) on server (i.e. web services) and reference it from the client browser application.

SDK does include Abis sample java applet. It can be built with Maven running from command prompt this command: "mvn clean install -Papplet"

From SDK\samples\biometrics\java directory (if SDK 5.0 is used)

From SDK\samples\ (if SDK 4.5 is used)

Maven version 3.1.1 is recommended.

I hope it can be useful.

**UPDATE 2**

I did an applet which capture the fingerprints and passed them to a javascript function.

**UPDATE 3**

I released an example [project](https://github.com/wiringbits/fingerprint-reader-daemon) to to this, explained in this [post](https://wiringbits.net/wiringbits/2020/03/20/reading-fingerprints-from-devices-on-webapps.html).

Comment: exactly how would html/javascript be able to talk to the reader?

Comment: html nor javascript are able to talk with hardware (as far as I know).

Comment: exactly. so you'll need a plugin/applet of some sort to handle the hardware access.

Comment: I don't know what kind of plugin can I use.

Comment: @vhax: I'm sure the extended SDK offers whatever browser technology is needed.  If you don't already have the extended SDK, contact VeriFinger, tell them you're already using the standard SDK, and see what they can do to get you a trial of the extended SDK (or at least the documentation).

Comment: thanks, I gonna do that.

Comment: @vhax so what did you end up doing?

Comment: @David Mauricio, I did an applet and updated my question with that.

Comment: What did you finally do ?

Comment: I did an applet which capture the fingerprints and passed them to a javascript function.

Comment: dear @vhax, after doing the applet, you were able to capture finger print and use it with the application? If yes can you please share it?

Comment: @ZaveedAbbasi yes, the project is private so I can't share it, the SDK contains a sample applet for that, you can use it and modify it.

Comment: @vhax how did you build a plugin for scanners if it's not supported by neurotec biometric sdk . Like 3M CSD200 scanner is not supported by neurotec biometric they only support 3M 330 scanner.

Comment: the device that I used is supported by the sdk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Verifinger SDK](http://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html) contains components for creating stand-alone or web-based applications.

> Available as a software development kit that allows development of stand-alone and Web-based solutions on Microsoft Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, iOS and Android platforms.

Comment: I forgot to say that, I can't find an example for doing it, can you provide me someone?

Comment: @vhax From the link in the answer **VeriFinger 7.0 SDK includes programming samples and tutorials that show how to use the components of the SDK to perform fingerprint template extraction or matching against other templates.**